# Add file type to Intellij Find in Files Mask

Tags: intellij-idea, markdown

I'd like to use Intellij's "Find in Files" window to search through our Markdown-based documents. However the list of file types seems limited and doesn't include "*.md".

[Find In File missing md extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4JiO.png)

Is there a way to add a file extension to this window?

I've tried searching for an option in Settings, but no success so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combobox is editable. You can type anything you want there.

Comment: #facepalm Yes. Yes it is!

Thanks Bas.